# Get valid cloud foundry oAuth token with post request

Tags: curl, cloud-foundry, developer-console, swisscomdev

If I successfully logged in to cloud foundry with `cf login` I can get a valid token with `cf oauth-token`.

How can I get a valid token with a curl call or post request with username and password?

Thank you and best regards.
Menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
 cf_user=youremail@example.com
 cf_password=yourpassword

 curl -X POST 'https://login.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/oauth/token' \
 -d "grant_type=password&scope=&username=${cf_user}&password=${cf_password}" \
 --user cf:
```

Hint: You can inspect the HTTP requests of a CLI command by setting `CF_TRACE=true`, i.e. `CF_TRACE=1 cf login`.

Comment: For the benefit of the community, please accept the answer, Franhu.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. With the following curl call I get a valid token:

`curl -X POST "yourloginserver/oauth/token"
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     -H "Accept: application/json"
     -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
     -H "Authorization: Basic Y2Y6"
     -d "grant_type=password"
     -d "username=my-user"
     -d "password=my-password"
     -m 30
     -v`

Comment: it should also work w/o "Authorization: Basic Y2Y6" header.